# How to restrict a column not to be reordered

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

In ngx-datatable i make first column not draggable then i can't drag it.
issue is that when i drag some other column which is draggable then it's order change.
i want stop it by both way.

````
  <!-- First column is not draggable -->
  <ngx-datatable-column [width]="30" [draggable]="false">
                            ...
  </ngx-datatable-column>
  <!-- The other columns are draggable -->
  <ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let column of dataColumns| slice:1; let i = index;" name="{{column.name}}" prop="{{column.prop}}" [draggable]="true">
  ...
  </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>```
````

Comment: Set a Boolean for each column in your TS file which changes based on which column in in first order and use that instead of statically giving true/false.

Comment: doing same thing as you said
freezeUnfreezeColumn(column, index: number, totalColumns?: number, columnId?: string,): void {
    if (index == 0 && columnId) {
      column["frozenLeft"] = this.freezeColumnData.firstColumnFreeze;
    } else if (totalColumns && index === totalColumns - 1) {
      column["frozenRight"] = this.freezeColumnData.lastColumnFreeze;
    }

Comment: Hammand: when i drag any unfreezed column to freezed column then it swap order with draggable column. it should not swap.

Comment: Why dont you keep it simple and create a variable for each column whos value will be set to either true or false based on the index of you column and assign that variable to the [draggable] property of your columns in your template. Like: <ngx-..... [draggable]="colACheck"> .... <ngx-..... [draggable]="colBCheck">

Comment: Frozen column is not draggable, it is working fine.
issue is when i drag and other column and drop it on frozen column then column will swap that should not haapen.